# What does this function do in PHP?

Tags: php

```
public static function getTournamentdetails($tournament_id) {

    $currentdate = date("Y-m-d")."00:00:00";

    $tournament_info = DB::table('tournaments as t')->select(
        't.tournament_id', 
        't.title', 
        't.console_id', 
        't.game_id',
        't.start_date', 
        't.bracket', 
        't.prize', 
        't.entry_fee',
        't.rules', 
        DB::Raw('DATE_FORMAT(t.start_date,"%b %d") AS start'), 
        'consoles.console_name',
        'games.game_name as game_name',
        DB::raw('IF(start_date <= "'.$currentdate.'" , 1, 0) as iscurrentlyenrolling')
    )
    ->leftjoin(
        'consoles AS consoles', 
        'consoles.console_id', 
        '=', 
        't.console_id'
    )
    ->leftjoin(
        'games AS games', 
        'games.game_id', 
        '=', 
        't.game_id'
    )
    ->where(
        't.tournament_id', 
        $tournament_id
    )
    ->get();

    $tournament_info[0]->rules = nl2br($tournament_info[0]->rules);

    ///$result = json_decode(json_encode($tournament_info), true);

    return $tournament_info;
}
```

I'm confused, especially regarding the currentdate variable - does it initialize the time as midnight?

Comment: `the time as midnight` Yes because they are to lazy, or dont know how to use `DATE()` in their query and the date format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, and if they dont do that they will miss some rows that are after or before the current time. And this `nl2br` converts `\n` line returns into `<br>` line break tags.  The rest of it looks like a pretty nasty query, but i don't like query builders so who knows what that does.

Comment: There's ways to debug this to see the raw query it generates before it's actually executed. The `$currentdate` though looks like it needs a space between the date and time if you're running into problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

`$currentdate` is assigned the current Year-month-date with midnight hour. The functions queries the database about all active tournaments and returns that data.

Comment: But the way it is done may miss some records... it depends on the intent of the authors.

Answer (score 0):

`$currentdate = date("Y-m-d")."00:00:00";` will return "2018-04-1000:00:00". MySql did not understand the day & hour part. Please add space `$currentdate = date("Y-m-d")." 00:00:00";` It will return exact mid night            ("2018-04-10 00:00:00").